# Create subset dataframes without loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Say we have our pandas dataframe, `df`:

```
             Foo       Bar
2018-01-01  0.568658  0.504093
2018-01-02  0.244716  0.422261
2018-01-03 -2.254264 -0.680178
2018-01-04  0.110540 -0.477153
2018-01-05 -1.342594 -0.005422
2018-01-06  1.219136  0.864694
2018-01-07  0.097513 -0.140353
```

And for each row in `df`, I wanted a slice equal to the next n rows,
lets say n=2 in this case:

```
2018-01-01  0.568658  0.504093
2018-01-02  0.244716  0.422261

2018-01-02  0.244716  0.422261
2018-01-03 -2.254264 -0.680178

2018-01-03 -2.254264 -0.680178
2018-01-04  0.110540 -0.477153

2018-01-04  0.110540 -0.477153
2018-01-05 -1.342594 -0.005422
```

etc. This is easily done within  a loop, but is there a pandas function for this kind of operation? Can it be done with group?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [pd.DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) function let's you produce such a moving window slice (called a rolling object) on which you can operate with various functions.

In your case, you would use:

```
df.rolling(2)
```

The functions you have access to on such a rolling object are listed in the docs under [window functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#window-functions).

Comment: I can probably use the apply on the rolling function though right? Ok got it now, thanks.

Comment: Yes, apply is one of the mentioned functions!